# Reference for the constant term of Eisenstein series on congruence/discrete subgroups

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, automorphic-forms

I'm looking for an exposition of the computation of the constant term of a non-holomorphic Eisenstein series associated to a discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ (or at least a congruence subgroup) of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, that is accessible to an advanced undergraduate. The more explicit the better.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do much better than Chapter 2 of "Spectral Methods of Automorphic Forms" by Iwaniec. The proof follows quickly from the Bruhat decomposition/double coset decomposition.